# Can I start a method from inside a preference?

Tags: android, xml, methods, preferences

Is it possible to start a method of a specific class from a preference instead of creating the object of the class?

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="facebook_cat"
    android:title="Σύνδεση με Facebook" >
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="facebook_screen"
        android:summary="Δεν έχετε συνδεθεί στο Facebook. Πατήστε κλικ εδώ για να συνδεθήτε."
        android:title="Αποσυνδεδεμένος" >
        <intent
         -->android:targetClass="com.testproject.facebook.FacebookConnectActivity" <--
            android:targetPackage="com.testproject" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

`facebookConnectActivity` is a class. Inside that class I have created a `public void called log()`.

Is it possible to start that instead of creating a whole object of `FacebookActivity` (hence starting the `log()` instead of `onCreate()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your method to be static:

```
public static void log()
```

And to call it from your Preference, just: `FacebookConnectActivity.log();`

And to be clear, you don't create objects that extends Activity, because there is no constructor there, you should call: `startActivity()` in order to call its `onCreate()` method, and the Activity will be visible for you.

Comment: i tried writing android:targetClass="com.testproject.facebook.FacebookConnectActivity.log()" but it said there weren't such classes with that name on the adroid manifest file... Since I got around a different approach, and since I got no more answers, i'll just upvote you and mark as answer. Thanks for the reply :)